# Reverse string in bash missing

Tags: bash, reverse

All,

I have a decrypt process which has a part that reverses an encoded (only as another ascii character) string.

The string is...

vtr«­¥ºc€a

And the reverse command I'm using is...

```
enc_pass="vtr«­¥ºc€a"
reverse=""

len=${#enc_pass}
for (( i=$len-1; i>=0; i-- ))
do
      reverse="$reverse${enc_pass:$i:1}"
done

echo $reverse
```

But when I check the length, it comes out as 9 characters long rather than 10, and I've found out its the € character which is being ignored.

Is there any way to cater for this? I'm pretty lost on it, not sure where to go next.

---

It turns out the main issue was with my LANG on the new server. The old server had LANG="en_GB" and the new server LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"

Changing the LANG back to en_GB resolved the reversing as UTF-8 ignored the character for some reason.

Comment: € is not an ascii character. Perhaps you could be clearer about the character encoding you are using.

Comment: @rici Maybe thats where I'm going wrong. The process that creates this phrase is built in VB.net and uses AscW fuction. I just assumed it was Ascii

Comment: Despite its name, `AscW` returns a Unicode code value: "AscW returns the Unicode code point for the input character. This can be 0 through 65535. The returned value is independent of the culture and code page settings for the current thread." (Unicode code values can actually be larger than 65535; I'm just quoting the docs I found on msdn.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
(your code)
echo "${#reverse}"
10

LC_ALL='C'
(your code)
echo "${#reverse}"
16
```

I think you must just have a localization/encoding problem in your environment. I suspect that would even effect `rev`, although it's a nonstandard utility so I can't say for sure. This works fine for me:

```
rev() {
    local -x LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
    if [[ ! "$1" ]]; then
        echo
        return
    fi
    printf '%s' "${1: -1:1}"
    rev "${1:0: -1}"
}
$ rev 'vtr«­¥ºc€a'
a€cº¥­«rtv
```

Comment: "nonstandard" -- /usr/bin/rev is in the debian "util-linux" package, which is categorized as an "essential" package ("the minimal set of functionality that must be available and usable on the system at all times"). For Linux anyway, it is a standard utility.

Comment: @glennjackman The word _standard_ is far more meaningful than just "does this utility exist" – it also informs how the utility behaves. It may be a defacto standard, but it isn't a POSIX utility. So BSD `rev` may behave differently from GNU `rev`, especially when it comes to nuances like localization.

Comment: @kojiro thanks for the solution, but I get an error "c-bash:  -1: substring expression < 0" when I use rev 'abc' (c-bash, c is always the last letter that I send through)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rev` utility:

```
enc_pass="vtr«­¥ºc€a"
rev <<< "$enc_pass"
a€cº¥­«rtv
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying that... "rev: stdin: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character"

Comment: Can you do: `LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'` and then run this `rev` command

Comment: First test this command with an ASCII string then repeat with unicode string. Make sure your terminal supports UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

rev command is of no great help, at least for binary files because rev terminates at 0x00.

```
$ export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
$ echo -e "\xe4" | rev
rev: stdin: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
$ 
$ export LC_ALL='de_DE.ISO-8859-1'
$ echo -e "\xe4" | rev | od -tx1
0000000 e4 0a
0000002
$ 
$ export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
$ echo -e "te\x00st" | rev | od -tx1
0000000 65 74 0a
0000003
$
```